# About execution order in makefile

Tags: makefile

in this Makefile:

```
ifeq ($(shell uname),Darwin)
    LDFLAGS := -Wl,-dead_strip
else
    LDFLAGS := -Wl,--gc-sections -lpthread -ldl
endif

all: target/double
    target/double

target:
    mkdir -p $@

target/double: target/main.o target/debug/libdouble_input.a
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

target/debug/libdouble_input.a: src/lib.rs Cargo.toml
    cargo build

target/main.o: src/main.c | target
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $<

clean:
    rm -rf target
```

when i excute `make all`, get this output:

```
hello_c_use_rust [master] ⚡  make all
mkdir -p target
cc -o target/main.o -c src/main.c
cargo build
   Compiling hello_c_use_rust v0.1.0 (/Users/jelly/code/own/hello_rust/hello_c_use_rust)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.20s
cc -o target/double target/main.o target/debug/libdouble_input.a -Wl,-dead_strip
target/double
4 * 2 = 8
```

Please tell me why this is the execution order ?  txs ^_^.
What puzzled me was why the first step was `mkdir -p target`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is `all`. `all` depends on `target/double` that must thus be done first. In turn `target/double` depends on `target/main.o` and `target/debug/libdouble_input.a`. So `target/main.o` and `target/debug/libdouble_input.a` must be done first. Here, you are lucky (we'll see why later): make tries to build `target/main.o` first. As `target/main.o` has `target` as a prerequisite, `target` must be done first and it is. Qed.

Note: `target` is an order-only prerequisite of `target/main.o`, not a regular prerequisite (the `|` sign starts the list of order-only prerequisites). It means that make pays only attention to its existence. It ignores its last modification time, which is good as last modification times of directories are usually not relevant in a build process.

Why is `target` a prerequisite of `target/main.o`? Because you cannot build `target/main.o` if the `target` directory does not exist yet. The build would simply fail. So the order-only prerequisite tells make that the directory must exist first.

Why are you lucky? Because if make had tried to build `target/debug/libdouble_input.a` first and if `cargo build` does not create the destination directory, it would have failed. Even if you know that `target/main.o` is built first because it is the first prerequisite of `target/double`, you should not count on this. One day or another somebody could try to use parallel make (`make -j`) and things could go wrong. Moreover `target` could exist but not `target/debug`...

Note: even if you know that `cargo build` takes care of creating the destination directory it is probably wise to add one more order-only prerquisite to your Makefile. Just in case something changes one day or another. And also to show readers of your Makefile that you know what you are doing here:

```
target target/debug:
    mkdir -p $@

target/debug/libdouble_input.a: src/lib.rs Cargo.toml | target/debug
    cargo build
```

It is not a big deal and could save you some errors.

Comment: oh ! you have provided so much for me !!  txs....... very very much!!